# What is the best way and How to implement jQuery code with Smooth scroll bar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is link of this smooth scroll js library https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/
What is best way to implement all related scroll event  for whole site.
Please help me in that very appreciating

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @Laif i have scroll based animation on my website i don't know how to use this library because its giving fake scroll transform based so native scroll event not working and also i don't get any scroll and offset on that.

Comment: I understand what you want, but we are not going to just teach you how to use a library. It has detailed documentation. If in the process of following this documentation you run into an issue you can't fix yourself, then post here again with a meaningful snippet and problem statement.